# Generate exportable AES keys in nCipher with JCE

Tags: encryption-symmetric, jce, hsm

I need to use nCipher HSM to generate AES256 keys and then export(write to file) them in external systems.

```
KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES", "nCipherKM");
kg.init(256);
SecretKey key = kg.generateKey();
//No problem until here
byte[] raw = key.getEncoded();
```

Throws a security exception. Wont give out the key. So I used below approach. Are both keys generated the same way ? Is there a better way to accomplish what I need?

```
SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("RNG", "nCipherKM");
byte[] rand = new byte[32];
random.nextBytes(rand);
SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(rand, "AES");
byte[] raw = key.getEncoded();
```

Thanks,

Vedat

Answer (score 3):

Vedat, the nCipherKM Provider generates actual key material on the Hardware Security Module(s) it connects to.  The HSM is designed to not let you have the actual key bits: keeping those secret is its purpose in life.

The second sequence will obtain random data from the HSM's random generator, which is a NIST Special Publication 800-90A compliant Deterministic Random Bit Generator seeded by hardware-based entropy.  This is the same type of random material the HSM uses internally to generate keys.  Since you don't seem to have any HSM protection requirements for the resulting keys, you should be good to go.